# Update query in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```sql
create table table1(accountno number);
insert into table1  values (1);
insert into table1 values (2);
insert into table1 values (3);
insert into table1 values (4);
insert into table1 values (5);
insert into table1 values (6);

create table table2(accountno number,check_y_n varchar2(20));

insert into table2 (accountno)  values (4);
insert into table2 (accountno) values (5);
insert into table2 (accountno) values (6);
insert into table2 (accountno) values (7);
insert into table2 (accountno) values (8);
insert into table2 (accountno) values (9);
```

I need below two update query in single query using joins. Can anyone help me on this

```sql
UPDATE TABLE2 SET check_y_n ='YES' WHERE accountno IN (SELECT accountno FROM TABLE1);

UPDATE TABLE2 SET check_y_n ='NO' WHERE accountno NOT IN (SELECT accountno FROM TABLE1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
UPDATE TABLE2
SET check_y_n = CASE
                WHEN accountno IN (SELECT accountno FROM TABLE1)
                THEN 'YES'
                ELSE 'NO'
                END;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/E7hfjE3T)*